# Creating related commit to a merged commit

Tags: git, gerrit

My team is using gerrit for code review. After merging a commit on gerrit, i wanted to create a new commit related to the old one. But i can't use same `task-id` (because my manager says it is a new task to fix the old problem and i can't use same `change-id` because the commit was already merged).

Besides my situation, how can i create a new commit that is related to a merged commit on gerrit without implying same `task-id`.

Thanks in advance

EDIT: I want to create a related commit because i want to track my changes on the issue. For new projects, we create patches to apply to the new project for solving old problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group changes by "topics". Using topics you can find related changes by using the topic search operator. Changes with the same topic are displayed on the change screen so you can navigate between them.

See more info [here](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/intro-user.html#topics).